# strange gap between input field in firefox

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a numpad button.  Here is fiddle code: [numpad](http://jsfiddle.net/3HbFN/)

if you open this in firefox, you may find there are two vertical gap ( e.g. between 1 and 2)

I'd like to eliminate those two gap, but have no clue where they are from in Firefox.

how to solve it?

Below is my HTML code:

```
     <div style="width: 755px; margin: 0 auto; ">
    <div class="button-pad">
            <input type="button" value="1" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="2" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="3" onclick="" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-pad">
            <input type="button" value="4" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="5" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="6" onclick="" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-pad">
            <input type="button" value="7" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="8" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="9" onclick="" />
        </div>
        <div class="button-pad">
            <input type="button" value="" />
            <input type="button" value="0" onclick="" />
            <input type="button" value="" onclick="" style="background-image:url(./img/clear.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.button-pad > input{
background-color: #EAEAEA;
border: 1px solid #666666;
color: #000000;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px;
width: 15%;

}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try adding `float:left` and adjust your widths to suit.

Comment: my side look fine, didn't found any problem

Comment: didn't you see the two blank gap?  between columns.....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3HbFN/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space, so you need to get rid of the space between your input elements:

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="" /><input type="button" value="2" onclick="" /><input type="button" value="3" onclick="" />
```

Also, if you want all the buttons to be directly adjacent to each other, change your CSS to:

```
.button-pad > input {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3HbFN/4/)**